# If $f$ is continuous and $I$ is an interval, then $f(I)$ is an interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

My prof says that the proof is not technically correct. But I didn't understand from his explanation how it is not correct. Can you please take a look and let me know why exactly my proof is not correct?

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $I$ be an interval, say $[a, b]$. Prove that $f(I)$ is an interval, where $f(I)=\{f(x), x\in I\}$.

> **Proof**:
>   Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(I)$ is not an interval. Then $\exists x \in I$ such that $f(x)\not\in f(I)$. By the Extreme Value Theorem, $\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)\ge f(y), \forall y\in I$. In particular, $f(c)\ge f(a)$. Also $\exists d \in [a,b]$ such that $f(d)\le f(y), \forall y \in I$. Thus $f(d)\le f(x)\le f(c)$. Since $f$ is continuous, and $f(d)$ and $f(c)$ are the end points of $f(I)$, $f(x)$ must be in $f(I)$. Hene, $f(I)$ is an interval.

Comment: $f(x) \in f(I)$ for $x \in I$ by definition of $f(I)$, so such an $x$ can't exist

Comment: 4 things wrong.  1) you claim if f(I) is not an interval there exist an x f (x) not in f (I).  That has nothing to do with intervals and doesn't follow.  Indeed it is utterly impossible by definition of f (I).  For all x in I f(x) must be in f (IL no matter what form f (I) is.  Then once stating that you never use it.  2) You claim you will do a proof by contradiction but you never do a contradiction.  3) you claim f (c) and f (d) are endpoints.  That implies f (I) is an interval which is what you need to prove.  You need to state they are extrema, not end points.

Comment: 4) you know the are extrema but you must prove that for all points y between f (d) and f (c) there is an x in I such that f (x) = y.  Otherwise maybe f (I) could be a bunch of separated points and intervals between f (d) and f (c).

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for pointing out my errors. Why can't we just say that if $f$ is continuous on $I$ then there can't be any $y\in f(I)$ such that $f^{-1}(y)\not\in I$? And hence $f(I)$ does not contain any "breaks", and is thus an interval.

Comment: you can... but it needs to be a bit more formal.  You actually did pretty good.  You showed the extreme value theorem implies for $f(x) \in f(I)$ then $f(c) \le f(x) \le f(d)$ i.e.  $f(x) \in [f(c), f(d)]$ i.e.  $f(I) \subseteq  [f(c), f(d)]$.  Use the intermediate value theorem to show that if $f(c) \le y \le f(d)$ there must exist an $x$ between $c$ and $d$ so that $f(x) = y$ so $y \in f(I)$ and therefore $ [f(c), f(d)] \subseteq f(I)$.

Comment: So, if $\forall y\in [f(c), f(d)]$, $\exists x\in [c, d]$, then how does this prove that $f(I)$ is an interval? Unless we use the same argument that $f$ is continuous, and thus there are no disconnected points. But then again, why not just argue that $f$ is continuous and thus has no disconnected points and call it a proof? I don't see what the rest of the proof is useful for. What exactly do we need to show in this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof 1.  Any non-empty interval $I$ is equal to $\cup_{n\in N}J_n$ where each $J_n$ is a non-empty bounded  closed interval with $J_{n+1}\supset J_n$ for each $n.$

Let $c_n, d_n\in J_n$ with $f(c_n)=\min \{f(x):x\in J_n\}$ and $d_n=\max \{f(x):x\in J_n\}.$

By the Intermediate Value Property, every $y \in (f(c_n),f(d_n)$ (if there is any) is equal to $f(x)$ for some $x$ between $c_n$ and $d_n$. Such $x$ belongs to $J_n.$ Therefore $$f(J_n)\supset [f(c_n),f(d_n)].$$  And $$f(J_n)\subset [f(c_n),f(d_n)]$$ by def'n of $c_n$ and $d_n.$ So $$f(J_n)=[f(c_n),f(d_n)].$$ Since $J_n\subset J_{n+1}$ we have $$f(c_{n+.1})\leq f(c_n)\leq f(d_n)\leq f(d_{n+1}.$$ So if we let $S=\inf_{n\in N}f(c_n)$ and $T=\sup_{n\in N}f(d_n)$ (allowing the possibilities  $S=-\infty$ or $T=\infty)$ then $$(S,T)\subset f(I)\subset [S,T].$$

Proof 2. By contradiction. Any $V\subset R$ is NOT an interval iff there exist $a,b,c\in T$ with $a,c\in T$ and $b\not \in T.$

If $f(I)$ is not an interval,find $x,y\in J$ with $f(x)=a<c=f(y),$ where some $b\in (a,c)\backslash f(I).$

But this contradicts the Intermediate Value Property, because every $b\in (f(x),f(y))$ is equal to $f(z)$ for some $z$ between $x$ and $y$, which makes $z\in I$  and  hence $b=f(z)\in f(I)$.

Proof 3. (i) Prove a subspace of $R$ is a connected space iff it is an interval. (ii) The continuous image of a connected space is a connected space.

Comment: Why can't we just say that if $f$ is continuous on $I$ then there can't be any $y\in f(I)$ such that $f^{-1}(y)\not\in I$? And hence $f(I)$ does not contain any "breaks", and is thus an interval.

Comment: Because for any function $f$ on any set $I$, we have $y\in f(I)\iff \exists x\in I\;(f(x)\in I)$  which tells us nothing about intervals.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious mistakes in your approach have been amply described in other answers. I would like to focus on providing a solution. Let's note that *a set $I$ of real numbers is called an interval if for any points $x, y \in I$ with $x < y$ we have $z \in I$ for all numbers $z$ satisfying $x < z < y$*. A set consisting of a single real number is also an interval according to this definition.

Now let $I$ be an interval and $f$ be a function from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f$ is continuous. If $f(I)$ is not an interval then there exist two points $a, b \in f(I)$ such that $a < b$ and there is a number $c \in (a, b)$ such that $c \notin f(I)$. Let $x, y \in I$ be such that $f(x) = a, f(y) = b$. Since $a < c < b$ therefore by intermediate value theorem there is a number $z$ between $x, y$ (so that $z \in I$) such that $f(z) = c$. Hence by definition of $f(I)$, the number $c$ lies in $f(I)$. We reach a contradiction and thus $f(I)$ must be an interval.

Thus *the result in question is an immediate consequence of the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.*

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $f(I)$ is not an interval. Then there is an $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in I$, either $f(x) < y$ or $y < f(x)$ and both the sets $\{x \in I\ |\ f(x)<y\}$ and $\{x \in I\ |\ y<f(x)\}$ are non-empty. Consider the intervals $I_1: = (-\infty, y)$ and $I_2:=(y,\infty)$. Then $f^{-1}[I_1]\cap f^{-1}[I_2]=\emptyset$. Since $f$ is continuous both pre-images of $I_1$ and $I_2$ under $f$ are open sets in $I$. But then $I=f^{-1}[I_1]\cup f^{-1}[I_2]$. Then $I$ is not an interval, since it is a union of two non-empty disjoint open sets.